# Windows Forms Desktop Shortcut

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have created a CRM system in Visual Studio 2010 using c#.net, and it's got to the point where I need to start deploying it.

When I publish, it creates an installer which just runs the program.

How can I get it to create a shortcut on the Desktop of the user installing it which will run my program?

Comment: I've used NSIS to build installers. It has a nice builtin shortcut function. What's your overall plan with the installer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume by "publish" you're using the publish options in the project properties.  If this is the case, there is a checkbox in the Publish Options dialog under Manifests that creates a desktop shortcut.

[image: Publish Options Dialog]

Comment: Where can I find this? I'm looking in the build menu (seems like an approprite place) and the others but can't see it.

Comment: Project menu, [project name] Properties, Publish tab.

Comment: Great that's sorted! Thanks! Do you know how to stop the "publisher cannot be verified" screen?

Comment: You will need to sign your ClickOnce manifests and application.  Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76e4d2xw.aspx for details.

Comment: For VS 2022 Go to Publish -> Settings -> Click Options -> Manifest -> Tick the "Create desktop shortcut".